# Django / Ajax / Datatable

Tags: ajax, django, datatable

I am trying to use following code in order to make a GET request to my django-based local server & render the obtained JSON-formatted data as a table:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var rows_selected = [];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'ajax': $("#active_subscriptions_url").attr("data-ajax-target"),
    'cache': true,
    'columnDefs': [{
       'targets': 0,
       'searchable':false,
       'orderable':false,
       'width':'1%',
       'className': 'dt-body-center',
       'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
       return '<input type="checkbox">';
       }
    }],
    'order': [1, 'asc'],
    'cache': true,
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
     // Get row ID
     var rowId = data[0];

     // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
     if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
        $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        $(row).addClass('selected');
     }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, it can not properly refer to the data, because each time this AJAX function adds a timestamp ad the end of a url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/?_=1530637137189
```

I can not get rid of it - I have tried using 'cache' paremeter in Ajax, but it does not work.
Moreover, I ve tried to extend my urls.py with following position:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<timestamp>\?_=[0-9]*)/$', ShowSubscriptions.as_view(), name='show_subscriptions'),
```

But it does not match the coming request at all.

Comment: If you try http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/ in browser tab does it work?

Comment: No, it says 'Page not found (404)', but your example is without the required 'timestamp' argument, so I bet that's the reason

Comment: Timestamp is added to all rest call to avoid cache issue...  I think problem is in your rest call....  First try to get rest call working in browser or postman.

Comment: The main point was to delete that timestamp from request, that is being generated. 
Are you able to help me with this one?